# NullPointerException in harmless line

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Our JUnit tests sometimes fail with this stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleMatcher.formatMatches(PatternRuleMatcher.java:300)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleMatcher.createRuleMatch(PatternRuleMatcher.java:158)
    [...]
```

Line 300 is this:

```
if (j >= positions.size()) {
```

`j` is an `int`, `positions` is `List<Integer>`, both are local variables. How can this cause a NullPointerException? I see no place in the code where 
`positions` is ever set to `null`. It gets initialized with `new ArrayList<>(tokens.length + 1)`. Actually, if I add `if (positions == null) { ... }` one line before where the exception occurs, IntelliJ even marks `positions == null` as a warning and tells me that will always be false.

The software uses threads but as both variables are local this shouldn't matter. The issue happens rarely, I have to run the tests maybe 30-40 times to get the problem.

What's going on here, can the line given by Java be off? (I'm sure I'm looking in the right file and right version, the file also doesn't change often).

This is with Java 1.8.0_51. The full code can be seen at https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-core/src/main/java/org/languagetool/rules/patterns/PatternRuleMatcher.java#L300

**Update**: complete stacktrace, as requested:

```
testRules(org.languagetool.rules.ca.CatalanPatternRuleTest)  Time elapsed: 29.978 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error analyzing sentence: '<S> Va[anar/VAIP3S00,Va/_GV_] haver[haver/VAN00000,heure/VMN00000,haver/_GV_] una[un/DI0FS0,una/_GN_FS] reunió[reunió/NCFS000,reunió/_GN_FS].[</S>./_PUNCT]'
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRule.match(PatternRule.java:191)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleTest.getMatches(PatternRuleTest.java:462)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleTest.testBadSentences(PatternRuleTest.java:294)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleTest.testGrammarRulesFromXML(PatternRuleTest.java:252)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleTest.runTestForLanguage(PatternRuleTest.java:187)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleTest.runGrammarRuleForLanguage(PatternRuleTest.java:103)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleTest.runGrammarRulesFromXmlTest(PatternRuleTest.java:91)
    at org.languagetool.rules.ca.CatalanPatternRuleTest.testRules(CatalanPatternRuleTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleMatcher.formatMatches(PatternRuleMatcher.java:300)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleMatcher.createRuleMatch(PatternRuleMatcher.java:158)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRuleMatcher.match(PatternRuleMatcher.java:136)
    at org.languagetool.rules.patterns.PatternRule.match(PatternRule.java:187)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: That line can and will cause a `NullPointerException` if the value of variable `positions` is `null`.  If the NPE is thrown at the line indicated, then that must be the case.  Since you seem to think that unlikely, do consider the possibility that you are looking at the wrong line.  That might happen, for instance, if the class file you are using was built from a different version of the source than you are looking at.

Comment: Run in a debugger and see for yourself?

Comment: @bmargulies so far the error only occurred when running the tests on the command line, not in the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue didn't occur with Java 7 and it doesn't happen anymore with Java 1.8.0_60. So this was actually a JVM bug, maybe this one: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8080156

Answer (score 4):

You can only rely on line numbers in the stacktrace if you are *absolutely certain* of the source file that was used to build the library.

In your case, the file in question has changed very recently. In fact, the contents of line 300 have changed [as seen by the diff](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/commit/382a953a217c3bef50ca47ef6af8887de6c1285b):

Moral of the story - don't trust stack trace line numbers unless you have the original source.

Comment: But that change was a reaction to the issue. I just got the exception an hour ago, the line number is 300 and line 300 in the current version of the file is `if (j >= positions.size()) {` - just as I wrote (before that change the error was in line 299 according to the stacktrace).

Comment: @DanielNaber So, it's not a library or you are using the source directly? In that case, you need to post the complete stack trace so we can see where `positions` is being created (or nulled).

Comment: I've added the stacktrace (although I'm not sure how to see from it where positions is null). The code is not an external library but my own.